# Run a declaration merging typescript test with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a jest project where I'd like to execute this test-file (in project/_ _ tests _ _/example.spec.ts):

```
module X.Y.Z {

    let r = X.Y.Z.C;

    describe("A", ()=>{
        it("Does A stuff", ()=>{
            expect(r).toEqual("someContent");
        });
    })
}
```

The source code (in project/src/source.ts) :

```
module X.Y.Z {

    export const C = "someContent";

}
```

My jest configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      "tsConfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.test.json"
    }
  },
  // transform: {
  //   "\\.(ts|js)x?$": "ts-jest",
  // },
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testMatch: [
      '<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.ts'
  ]
};
```

The tsConfig.test.json file :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "inlineSources": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
     "./src/source.ts"
  ]
}
```

Test's execution fails on a syntaxError:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/example.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: C:\Users\Workspace\jest-typescript\__tests__\example.spec.ts: Unexpected token, expected ";" (1:7)

    > 1 | module X.Y.Z {
        |        ^
      2 | 
      3 |     let r = X.Y.Z.C;
      4 | 

      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6325:17)
```

Anybody knows how I may be able to bring jest to execute this test ? Thanks !

Comment: what is this `module X.Y.Z` syntax?

Comment: It has been a thing in typescript 2.7.1 (which is the one is use), it's like in C# I guess, once you compile the typescript files the modules bundle-up, it's a way of joigning together bits of code that belong to the same "namespace" on different files.

Comment: Oh, do you mean `declare module {...}` like shown here? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#nodedts-simplified-excerpt  . I don't think its possible to use that in .ts files, only in .d.ts files.

Comment: You actually can, you just have to transpile all the files containing the modules together, for example if you transpile the`example.spec.ts` with the `source.ts` you'll have a js file in output over which you can run your tests, however, I'd like to run it on the .ts file directly to get the coverage and so forth !

Comment: Thanks for the info, actually never saw that syntax. If I put this construct in a codesandbox, eslint complains: "ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces." Maybe that's a slight hint to better go for ES modules...?

Comment: You're right ! I'd like to go for the `import` statements, but I am working on a legacy code-base with that oldy syntax.